# Django correct operators for running total

Tags: django

I'm trying to get all the totals of all item.estimated_cost in a var I can use...

```
 batches = Batch.objects.for_user_pending(request.user)
    total_estimated_cost = 0
    for item in batches:
        total_estimated_cost =+ item.estimated_cost
```

But I'm getting this error:

**bad operand type for unary +: 'instancemethod'**

**model method **

```
def estimated_cost(self):
        return len(self.content) / 160 + 1 * self.group.contact_set.count()
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: use classmethods so that you can pass variables. what's the error? or what you have encountered?

Comment: @wRAR  how do I do this in django:  total_estimated_cost = total_estimated_cost + item.estimated_cost

Comment: @catherine  posted error above.

Comment: ok now tell me what is the operation must be executed first and the next? you didn't put any `()` in your operations

Comment: Hi @catherine  so I have updated the code I have as I have it. all I ant to do is get the total in a var off all the item.estimated_cost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def estimated_cost(self):
    return (int(len(self.content)) / 160) + (1 * int(self.group.contact_set.count()))

batches = Batch.objects.for_user_pending(request.user)
total_estimated_cost = 0
for item in batches:
    total_estimated_cost += item.estimated_cost()
```

Comment: swap `+` and `=`. close `item.estimated_cost()`. enclose field variable with `int` to ensure that it is a number not a string.